# Flask form is not validating after validation fails once

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I have a basic form which I validate with flask validate() method.

If completely fill the form without any error and submit it, it works.

If I fill it partly, and click submit, the validation kicks in and highlights the errors.

The problem is that, even after correcting the errors, the submit-button does simply not work anymore.
i have a custom validation function too.
The code is below.

What could be wrong here?.

here is my form definition.

```
import sys
sys.dont_write_bytecode = True

from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField, SelectField, IntegerField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, optional, StopValidation

def myvalidation(form,field):
    a = form.price_select.data != 'F'
    b = field.data is None
    if a and b:
        print(field.errors)
        raise StopValidation()

class search_item(FlaskForm):
    brand = StringField('product brand',validators = [optional()])
    item = StringField('product title', validators=[DataRequired()])
    price_select = SelectField('under or above', choices=[('F','under or above'),('D','under'),('E','above')])
    price = IntegerField(validators=[myvalidation, optional()])
    search = SubmitField('search')
```

and here is my view function.

```
def given():
    if session.get('default') is None:
        print('check1')
        form = search_item(price_select = 'F')
    elif (session['default'] == 'F'):
        print('check2')
        form = search_item(price_select = 'F',brand=session['errname0'],item=session['errname1'],price=session['errname2'])
    elif session['default'] != 'F':
        print('check3')
        form = search_item(price_select= session['default'],brand=session['errname0'],item=session['errname1'],price=session['errname2'])
    print(form.item.data)
    print(form.validate_on_submit())
    if request.method == 'POST' and form.validate():
        print('check4')
        session.clear()
        session['comp'] = re.sub("[^a-z0-9 ]+", '', form.brand.data.strip().lower())
        session['product'] = re.sub("[^a-z0-9 ]+", '', form.item.data.strip().lower())
        if form.price.data is not None:
            session['price_select'] = form.price_select.data
            session['cost'] = form.price.data
        return redirect(url_for('result'))
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        print('check5')
        session['err'] = form.item.errors
        session['errname0'] = form.brand.data
        session['errname1'] = form.item.data
        session['errname2'] = form.price.data
        session['err2'] = form.price.errors
        session['default'] = form.price_select.data
        return redirect(url_for('given'))
    if session.get('err') is not None and session.get('err2') is not None:
        print('check6')
        fault = []
        if len(session['err']) != 0:
            fault1 = session['err'][0]
            fault.append(fault1)
        else:
            fault.append('')
        if len(session['err2']) != 0:
            fault2 = session['err2'][0]
            fault.append(fault2)
        else:
            fault.append('')
        session.clear()
        return render_template('find.html', form=form, err=fault)
    else:
        print('check7')
        return render_template('find.html', form=form)
```

Comment: Why are you checking `request.method == POST` twice? Also I don't think you need to check for `request.method == POST` if you are using flask_wtf. Just use `form.validate_on_submit()` method and remove request check. `if form.validate_on_submit(): your code`

Comment: @Aditya i tried it too but the problem remains same.

Comment: Maybe none of the if/elif check in your view function is returning true once the validation fails and so you are not getting the form back. Also make sure you have included `method=POST` in your HTML form tag.

Comment: @Aditya I have checked this too but this is not the case too.